# Opensource Feed / Wall plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a plugin that can make JSON data into a Facebook Wall-like view? Using jQuery or any other JavaScript toolkits?

I found quite few ones online, however I am looking for those most mature plugins to use.

Comment: Maybe you could write what plugins you've already found and add that to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this soultion.

http://www.9lessons.info/2014/10/wall-script-social-network-software.html

I'ts facebook wall like script. There are implementation documents in the same website.